# Extract <svg> element by using document.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, xpath, svg, dom-manipulation, document.evaluate

I am trying to use `document.evaluate()` to extract certain child elements out of a `<svg>` element. But I have problems by just extracting the `<svg>` itself. I can extract everything up to the `<svg>`, but no further. For example this works well :

```js
document.evaluate('//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue)
```

This gives me (shortened) :

```html
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-label="Et diagram.">
    <svg width="600" height="400" aria-label="Et diagram." style="overflow: hidden;"></svg>
    <div aria-label="En repræsentation i tabelformat af dataene i diagrammet." style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

and then I would assume the simple

```
//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div/svg
```

would give me the `<svg>` - but nothing works. Have tried all respond types :

```js
for (var type=XPathResult.ANY_TYPE; type<XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE+1; type ++) {
   console.dir(
      document.evaluate('//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div/svg', document, null, type, null)
   );   
}
```

I get either `invalidIteratorState`, null `singleNodeValue` or a `snapshotLength` of 0.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hw79zp7j/**

Is there any limitations of `evaluate()` I havent heard of, or am I just doing it utterly wrong?

For clarification, my ultimate goal is to be able extract for example a google visualization `xAxis` `<text>` elements in a single line of code. As it is now (see demo) I have to iterate through the `<svg>` by using multiple `querySelectorAll` / `getElementsByTagName` etc, which is not very readable, maintenance friendly or elegant. It would be nice just to grab the `xpath` from google developer tools and reuse it in a single line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SVG elements are in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` and to select elements in a namespace with XPath you need to bind a prefix to the namespace URI and use that prefix in your path to qualify the element names e.g. `svg:svg`. So use a resolver as the third argument of `evaluate` that maps the prefix you can choose (e.g. `svg`) to the namespace URI mentioned above.

```
document.evaluate('//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div/svg:svg', document, 
                                function(prefix) { 
                                    if (prefix === 'svg') 
                                    { 
                                        return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }, type, null)
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Actually I had been looking for a namespace inside the `<svg>` (as `xmlns="xxx"` or similar), but since there was none I assumed it was not nessecary. So the namespace is always implicit for `<svg>` elements? Anyway, the next thing was to get further, after some small testing I realize it is the same down the hiearchy,  `//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div/svg:svg/g:g` etc - so I will eventually be able to do an automated `//*[@id="chart"]/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[3]/g[3]` oneliner by taking care of the above. Thank you!

Comment: XPath was originally defined for XML documents using namespaces and in XML you would need to write `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>` to mark up an SVG element properly and have any user agent recognize your SVG. But these days we live in the world of HTML5 where a mixture of HTML, SVG and MathML is allowed without declaring any namespaces. Nevertheless, the elements have a namespace and even selecting HTML without a prefix works only as the HTML5 specification says so in http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#interactions-with-xpath-and-xslt.