# How to click on svg element using xpath with document.evaluate

Tags: svg, document.evaluate

I need to click on an add button, when i am inspecting it, i am getting a xpath

```
//li[text()='Alabama']//ancestor::ul//li[2]//*[local-name()='svg']
```

the HTML code is given below

```
<div class="available-state-list scroll-bar">
 <ul>
     <li>Alabama</li>
     <li><svg width="16" height="15" viewBox="0 0 16 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M3.00774 2.16391C0.246501 4.93321 0.246501 9.43934 3.00774 12.2087C5.76898 14.978 10.262 14.978 13.0232 12.2087C15.7845 9.43934 15.7845 4.93322 13.0232 2.16391C10.262 -0.605398 5.76898 -0.605398 3.00774 2.16391ZM11.0972 6.6401C11.1699 6.63823 11.2422 6.65098 11.3099 6.67759C11.3776 6.70419 11.4393 6.74413 11.4914 6.79503C11.5434 6.84593 11.5848 6.90677 11.6131 6.97397C11.6413 7.04116 11.6559 7.11335 11.6559 7.18628C11.6559 7.25921 11.6413 7.33139 11.6131 7.39859C11.5848 7.46579 11.5434 7.52663 11.4914 7.57753C11.4393 7.62843 11.3776 7.66836 11.3099 7.69497C11.2422 7.72158 11.1699 7.73433 11.0972 7.73246L8.56031 7.7327L8.56007 10.277C8.55643 10.4194 8.49746 10.5548 8.39573 10.6542C8.29399 10.7537 8.15755 10.8093 8.01548 10.8093C7.87341 10.8093 7.73697 10.7537 7.63523 10.6542C7.5335 10.5548 7.47452 10.4194 7.47089 10.277L7.47065 7.7327L4.93379 7.73246C4.79177 7.72881 4.65679 7.66967 4.55763 7.56764C4.45847 7.46561 4.40297 7.32876 4.40297 7.18628C4.40297 7.0438 4.45847 6.90695 4.55763 6.80492C4.65679 6.70289 4.79177 6.64374 4.93379 6.6401L7.47065 6.63985L7.47089 4.09559C7.47452 3.95315 7.5335 3.81778 7.63523 3.71833C7.73697 3.61888 7.87341 3.56322 8.01548 3.56322C8.15755 3.56322 8.29399 3.61888 8.39573 3.71833C8.49746 3.81778 8.55643 3.95315 8.56007 4.09559L8.56031 6.63985L11.0972 6.6401Z" fill="#1D54B4">
          </path>
        </svg>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>......</ul>
  <ul>......</ul>
</div>
```

so i tried to click on that svg element using below code

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
}
getElementByXpath("//li[text()='Alabama']//ancestor::ul//li[2]//*[local-name()='svg']").click();
```

i have seen one solution in [Extract <svg> element by using document.evaluate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162358/extract-svg-element-by-using-document-evaluate) .So tried it in my code as given below

```
document.evaluate("//li[text()='Alabama']//ancestor::ul//li[2]//svg:*[local-name()='svg']", document, 
                            function(prefix) { 
                                if (prefix === 'svg') 
                                { 
                                    return 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

but it shows an error as document.evaluate(...).singleNodeValue.click is not function. Am i going wrong? Can any one help to click on this element using xpath expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: click is a function available on HTML elements only, it is not something you can call on SVG elements.

Comment: Can you post the markup of your document?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the HTML code.